# .htaccess rewriting with multiple $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm really struggling to write my .htaccess file properly. I would like the following to happen:

1. x.domain.com **--> redirect to -->** domain.com/index.php?id=x
2. If there is a $_GET variable on the original URL, transfer this to the second URL: x.domain.com/?y
   **--> redirect to -->** domain.com/index.php?id=x&y

So far, I've managed to get as far as mentioned in the **1st point**.

But can't work out where to go next to achieve the **2nd point**.

Do I need to write new lines for a separate rule, or amend the current lines?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=%1 [L,P]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=%1 [L,P,QSA]
```

You're looking for the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (query string append) flag, which appends the query string back to the rewritten URL.